# How can I use "fill someone in" passive voice?

Tags: phrase-usage, passive-voice

Recently I get to know the phrase "fill someone in". I am not sure the usage of the phrase in a passive voice sentence.

Is this correct?

*What I was filled in today is that we are planning a big project!*

Comment: John filled me in on the details. -> Today, the details were filled in for me by John.

Comment: Normally the passive promotes the direct object. _Fill in_ is a phrasal verb (hence _fill me in_ instead of *_fill in me_), and it's normally not transitive (unless it's literal: _Fill in the hole/box_). In its communicational sense it means to "fill in the blanks" -- update one's information on the state of a joint undertaking, while proceeding with it. So it's mostly concerned with the indirect object; if a direct object is needed, it takes _about_ or _on_, and can be passivized with a stranded preposition. The last sentence is ungrammatical, but it'd be OK with _in on_ instead of just _in_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I don't see how stranding the preposition could work here. **Active**: *They filled me in on the plan.* **Passive**: *\*The plan was filled in on . . .*

Comment: @TinfoilHat: No, you're right. The content phrase (_on the plan_) can't be passived. Only the indirect object - _He was filled in on the plan_. Note that the present tense is not a passive but a predicate adjective -- _He's filled in on the plan_ means he's currently in a state of knowledge; it doesn't refer to an event.

Comment: @Greybeard: The active version of your passive sentence is *Today, John filled in the details for me.* *Fill in* is different than *fill [someone] in on*.

Comment: Without an indirect object, however, you can say *they filled me in* and *I was filled in.*

Comment: Do bear in mind that "fill in" used in this sense of "filling someone in" with information etc., is colloquial and a relatively modern expression. The earliest reference the OED has, is from 1945. There are plenty of other more erudite ways of saying the same thing e.g. "Please, could you provide me with the full details about the matter".

Comment: You need to be a little careful in Britain of using "fill in". It is slang for to beat someone up e.g. *They filled him in and took his money*. It is shown as sense 6 in the OED. Nonetheless *fill in* is used in the UK as described here - but take care, as context could create an unfortunate play on words.

Answer (score 4):

That's almost right, but the wording sounds a little clunky. It sounds like there might be an "about" missing, since "filled in" isn't a direct substitute of "told" in all cases. For example, "What did you tell him?" cannot be replaced by "What did you fill him in?" - it would have to be "What did you fill him in *on*?" or "What did you fill him in *about*?"

The phrasing "what I was filled in" is an odd-sounding subject for the sentence, it would be better to include "about" - *What I was filled in about today is that we are planning a big project.* Of course, that wording is a bit clunky as well, so you should probably just say:

> *I was filled in today that we are planning a big project.*

Answer (score 4):

You need the phrasal-prepositional verb* [*fill in on*](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/fill.html) here:

> **Active**: *The company filled me in on our plans for a big project.*
>
> **Passive**: *I was filled in on our plans for a big project.*
>
> **Your active version**: *What the company filled me in **on** today **is**
>   that we are planning a big project!*
>
> **Your passive version**: *What I was filled in **on** today **is** that we
>   are planning a big project!*

You could use the preposition *about* instead of *on*. But to follow *filled in* with a *that*-clause is not idiomatic usage. Here are examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

[filled [pronoun] in on](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=88513461) (179)

[filled [pronoun] in about](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=88513473) (16)

[filled [pronoun] in that](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=88513450) (1)

.

<sub>*See: [Phrasal verbs and multi-word verbs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs)</sub>